# CMake... ccmake or cmake?

Tags: cmake

What is the difference between `cmake` and `ccmake`? I have the Ubuntu package `cmake` installed, and on my Windows computer, I have the installer from the website, but neither have the command `ccmake` available. Yet, [the tutorials](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/-/wikis/FAQ), seem to reference it quite regularly.

It seems that `ccmake` on Unix is `CMakeSetup` on Windows (which is the setup program). But I'm a little confused about it; is it just an alternative to manually typing your own `CMakeLists.txt` files?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Both are [interactive dialogues for CMake](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/index.html#interactive-dialogs) (as opposed to primarily-command-line tools).

Quoting from [the documentation for `ccmake`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/ccmake.1.html):

> The [`ccmake`] executable is the CMake curses interface. Project configuration settings may be specified interactively through this GUI. Brief instructions are provided at the bottom of the terminal when the program is running.

Quoting from DLRdave's answer to [a question about running CMakeSetup](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7979490/11107541):

> CMakeSetup is an older program that no longer builds with the most recent releases of CMake. Use "cmake-gui" instead of "CMakeSetup"...

Quoting from [the documentation for `cmake-gui`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-gui.1.html):

> The cmake-gui executable is the CMake GUI. Project configuration settings may be specified interactively. Brief instructions are provided at the bottom of the window when the program is running.

Comment: use the word "GUI" loosely with ccmake!

Comment: in linux there is also a `cmake-gui`, which is a truly graphical GUI

Answer (score 50):

`ccmake` is the curses (terminal handling library) interface to CMake.

`cmake` is the CLI (Command Line Interface)

Answer (score 15):

***ccmake*** :
It is teminal based GUI to edit the default options or paths in `CMakeLists.txt`.
***Usage***:
After you have generated configure files using `cmake ..` in `build` folder. Then do `ccmake ..` , to see all the options and paths which can be be modified by pressing `Enter` for editing. After editing press `c` again to configure. This will save the files in build folder with your edited settings. Then do `make -j4` , for building the `MakeFile`.

Comment: cmake worked and generated multiple files in the build folder but ccmake creates this response: "ccmake : The term 'ccmake' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and
try again."

Comment: @Ben, your error seems like an environment variable issue. Please check this issue https://stackoverflow.com/q/59503747/8739732

Answer (score 4):

ccmake (for Unix) and CMakeSetup (for NT) are indeed equivalent: a UI to cmake. They basically call cmake and display how your project is configured, what libraries have been found and where (for libraries referenced with FIND_LIBRARY. It gives you a chance to review and modify these variables before generating the Makefile or project.

Comment: I believe the recommendation is to use cmake-gui.exe on NT. I couldn't find a proper link to support that though.