# How to run CMakesetup?

Tags: cmake

I downloaded cmake and I wanted to build LSHKIT using this command:
cmakesetup ", where  is the LSHKIT root directory
but it gives me this error:
'cmakesetup' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

could you tell me what is wrong?
BTW, I am working in windows 7.

Answer (score 5):

CMakeSetup is an older program that no longer builds with the most recent releases of CMake. Use "cmake-gui" instead of "CMakeSetup"...