# The term 'cmake' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: windows, powershell, cmake, environment-variables

I am trying to use CMake in the command line on Windows 10. This used to work before, but I don't know why it doesn't work anymore. I installed new version of CMake and added the path to the Environment Variables. However, when trying to use it in Powershell like this:
`cmake -G "Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64" ..`

it shows this error:

> cmake : The term 'cmake' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script
>   file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included,
>   verify that the path is correct and try again.
>   At line:1 char:1

This is my Environment Variables:

[image]

I have added `C:\Program Files\CMake\bin` to the end of the `path` variable. I have also tried uninstall and reinstalling CMake, but didn't help.

Comment: what is in the path variable as seen in your powershell session? use `$env:Path -split ';'` to see what the value is in the session.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey I saw it. It is exactly the same , except the last line `C:\Program Files\CMake\bin` is not in the powershell path.

Comment: then you need to add it BEFORE the PoSh session starts OR you need to add it _inside_ the current PoSh session. it really otta be part of your permanent path, so i would add it prior to starting powershell.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey I added it to the permanent path before starting the PowerShell, but did not work. However, adding it ***inside*** the current PowerShell works. Maybe I should reinstall PowerShell.

Comment: reinstalling PoSh will NOT change the problem. [*grin*] you can make a permanent change from inside your PoSh session for that account by using the dotnet method shown here >>> `Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable Method (System) | Microsoft Docs — https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.setenvironmentvariable?view=netframework-4.8` <<<

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In current powershell session, you have to add the path to path environment variable. You have to use this:

```
$env:path += ";C:\Program Files\cmake\bin"
cmake -g ...
```

Comment: Thank you this works. But I have to do this everytime I open PowerShell. Is there a way to add it to path permanently?

Comment: Yes, you have to use this `cmd /c setx.exe PATH "%PATH%;C:\Program Files\Cmake\Bin"`.