# Cannot call ccmake

Tags: windows, powershell, cmake, environment-variables

I was able to build files via `cmake ..` but when I try to call `ccmake ..` I receive this:

```
(base) PS C:\geant4\B1_mod\build> ccmake ..
ccmake : The term 'ccmake' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and
try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ ccmake ..
+ ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (ccmake:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

According to [The term 'cmake' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59503747/the-term-cmake-is-not-recognized-as-the-name-of-a-cmdlet) some environment variables are not set but when I check them:

```
(base) PS C:\geant4\B1_mod\build> $env:Path -split ';'
C:\Users\User\Anaconda3
C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin
C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\Library\usr\bin
C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\Library\bin
C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\Scripts
C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\bin
C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\condabin
C:\Windows\system32
C:\Windows
C:\Windows\System32\Wbem
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0
C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH
C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Scripts\HP.ClientScriptLibrary
C:\Program Files\CMake\bin
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit
C:\Program Files\Geant4-11.0\bin
C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet
C:\Program Files\dotnet
C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\cmd
C:\geant4\geant4-build\bin
```

I think it's correct. However, the command `cmd /c setx.exe PATH "%PATH%;C:\Program Files\Cmake\Bin"` didn't help, anyway. What's wrong, what shall I do?

Comment: Since `cmake` is available but `ccmake` is not, it seems you have **installed** CMake **without** interactive tool based on curses interface (this is what [ccmake](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/ccmake.1.html) is). Note that there is also GUI tool, [cmake-gui](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-gui.1.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Can I add these interactive tools somehow?